# How to get information on agregate object with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a request that use a group by to get the MIN distance between two object.

```
WITH point_interet AS (
    SELECT pai.ogc_fid as p1id, pai2.ogc_fid as p2id, MIN(ST_Distance(pai.geom, pai2.geom)) AS distance
    FROM point_activite_interet pai
    JOIN point_activite_interet pai2 ON pai.ogc_fid > pai2.ogc_fid
    GROUP BY pai.ogc_fid)
SELECT * FROM point_interet
ORDER BY distance DESC;
```

This doesn't work because Postgres says p2id should be in GROUP BY clause actually it is not true, I would like to know what is the object the closest from pai.ogc_fid.

Do you have any idea how I should do that?

Comment: Why shouldn't p2id be in the GROUP BY? It's not part of an aggregate.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, I want p2id to be the id which one is the closest of the p1id.

Comment: OK - try dropping the MIN() + GROUP BY, keep the ORDER BY DESC and add a LIMIT 1 to the end. You don't need the WITH stuff either.

Comment: Well ok you are right.

Comment: With nearest neighbor queries like this you probably also want to include an st_dwithin condition, otherwise you're doing a cross query on all geometries, which can become very expensive very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to remove the `min()` aggregate

Alternatively you could add a window specification, such as `min(...) OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` which would allow you to do this, but I don't think this is what you want because it will give you the minimum distance of any preceding row compbination.....